# Angular acceleration to linear acceleration for a rope and beam

Tags: rotational-kinematics

So say that I have a beam that can rotate around a pivot, with a rope attached at some radius. The rope also always passes through another point such that the length of the rope from this point to where it is attached is calculated with a 2d distance formula, and can be written as a function of the beam's angle, such that $x$, the rope displacement, equals $f(\theta)$ .

Now say that torque is applied to the beam that causes an angular acceleration. How do I find the linear acceleration for the rope's length (between the attachment and the point of passthrough)? My best guess is that this is a related rates problem where the acceleration equals the second derivative of $f(\theta)$ at the beam's angle $\theta$ multiplied by the angular acceleration:

$$ a=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2} \cdot \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2},\quad f''(\theta)=\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2} $$

At first it seemed like the units were not correct since there is a higher degree of radians on the bottom, but apparently radians are unitless so this does not matter. Does this equation make sense at all or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Consider to include a diagram.